# Angular: View not updated inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a custom view directive inside a ng-repeat list like this:

```
//Directive
app.directive("card", function () {
  return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "views/card.html"
  };
});

...

//List
<card ng-repeat="card in cards = main.data.getCards() | filter: sidebar.search() | orderBy: ['isPinned',$index]:true track by $index"
      ng-if="content.checkCard(card)">
</card>
```

main.data is a reference to a service, where the data is being stored.
Here is a simplified version:

```
app.service('data', function ($http, engine) {
var cards = [];
...

return {
    getCards: function () {
        return cards;
    },
    setCards: function (data) {
        cards = data;
        engine.save("cards", cards);
    },
```

When the data changes through the setCards() method, my list shows only empty elements. If I use the exact same html code inside my ng-repeat directly however, everything works fine. What can I do?

Comment: can you reproduce your problem at plunker ?

Comment: this can cause by many reason, specify your error, it would help to rectify

Comment: I solved the problem, it was abug not related to the question. Works fine now, thanks anyway ;)